# Media Query for Mobile Changes Desktop View

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have zero coding experience and have been working on my portfolio using cargo. I'm currently trying to adjust the mobile view of one of my articles on my home page using media queries, but the code seems to change the layout on desktop as well. I'll drop reference pictures below of the desired mobile and desktop views, as well as the current code I'm working with. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**(disregard the borders in the code, this was mostly for visibility purposes when making changes)

Here's my code:

```html
<style>
    .tiffany {
    /*border: solid green 3px;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .tiffany img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .tiffany .textbox {
    /*border: solid red 3px;*/
    position: absolute;
    margin: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .resize_tiffany {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  .tiffany .gradient {
    /*border: solid red 3px;*/
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* other styles (left, top, right, and padding) */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), transparent);
  }
  /* read-here */
  
  .read-here {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4vw;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 68, 11);
    color: rgb(0, 68, 11);
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    font color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480) {
    .tiffany .textbox {
      border: solid blue 3px;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480) {
      /* read-here */
      .read-here {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 4vw;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: rgb(0, 68, 11);
        color: rgb(0, 68, 11);
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        font color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
      }
    }
</style>

<div class="tiffany">
  <img class="background-image" src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/49f84023695066f70817f10d5164bfc85e438f33abd59b9c50a439f6a22f0454/Featured-Page_Tiffany_Alfonseca_Latina_Edit.jpeg">
  <div class="gradient">
    <div class="textbox full-pointer-events-none">
      <h1> <span class="resize_tiffany">Tiffany Alfonseca Pays Homage in Painting</span></h1>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="read-here">
      <bodycopy> <b><a href="https://latina.com/tiffany-alfonseca-pays-homage-in-painting/" target="_blank">Read here</a></b> </bodycopy>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br></div>
```

Comment: I'm more than happy to add my portfolio for viewing as well!

Comment: you might need to add the unit at the end of the width: `max-width(480px)`

Comment: check the brackets around the mediaqueries, you're missing some closing brackets I think. also units for 480 as has been mentioned

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) I'm having issues with changing the font size now as well  .tiffany .textbox {
  /*border: solid red 3px;*/
  position: absolute;
  margin: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .tiffany .textbox {
      font-size: 2vw;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      left: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
 }
}

Comment: There is no such thing as `<bodycopy>` Where are you getting that?

Comment: I'm using cargo collective to create my website, and within their web design you set different fonts for different aspects of your page, so that code is on cargo's front.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added in the px like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
}
```

Also I would highly recommend using rem instead of vw for the font-size. You can read more about that on: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-rem-in-css/

Essentially, If you don't specify font-size the default is 16px, 1rem would therefore be equal to 16px, 2rem = 32px and so on.